# How to do a numerical range in a single cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

For a spreadsheet idea i wanted to make a point based system depending on how many calories were consumed within a day, to do this I wanted to do a range style system
I know in OOP languages you would take a variable, and do an IF ELSE (or switch) statement, but i'm not quite sure how to do it in a spreadsheet

```
=IF(D11<900,"-200"),=IF(D11<1200,"200"), =IF(D11<1500,"0")
```

In this code i wanted it so that, if less than 900 calories are consumed, there will be a 200 point penalty, and then from 900-1200 calories there is 200 points granted and then from then on like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the IF

```
=IF(D11<900,-200,IF(D11<1200,200,IF(D11<1500,0,"Greater than 1500")))
```

Comment: Ohh, thank you! that makes sense, I had a feeling it'd be something simple

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(D11, {0, -200; 900, 200; 1200, 0; 1500, "GREATER THAN 1500"}, 2, 1)
```

[image]

see: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**